# Cut number and add "/" between php

Tags: php

I have a variable

```
$variable=12345;
```

and i want to separate each number and add a / between them:

**Expected output:**

```
$variable = 1/2/3/4/5;
```

Comment: Tip: `str_split()` + `foreach()` OR  `preg_replace()`

Comment: can you tell us why you need to do this? Maybe there's a better approach. Wanting just `$variable = 1/2/3/4/5;` simply echos `0.0083333333333333`, you know that, right? That variable declaration's state is unclear as is the question.

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: It is a string or integer? If string will it ever contain non-numbers? `preg_replace('/(\d(?!$))/', '$1/', $string);` seems like it'd do it.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest could be this. Here we are using `str_split` and `implode`. `str_split` will convert string into array and `implode` join the array with given character.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$variable=12345;
echo $array= implode("/",str_split($variable));
```

**Output:**
`1/2/3/4/5`